# Style not working on angular sidebar toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sidebar

I am new to Angular and installed `ng-sidebar` component through **NPM,** I have designed my sidebar:

**component.html:**

```
<ng-sidebar-container>
    <ng-sidebar 
        [(opened)]="_opened"
        mode="push"
        autoCollapseWidth=500>
        <div>
            <!-- Sidebar-content goes here -->
        </div>

    </ng-sidebar>

    <div ng-sidebar-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <a id="show-sidebar" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" href="#" (click)="_toggleSidebar()">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

</ng-sidebar-container>
```

Now, I have a toggle button above with id `#show-sidebar`, I want to apply `left: 300px;` on it when sidebar opened, for that I looked up the console and found an attribute on `ng-sidebar` tag as `ng-reflect-opened`, then I wrote the following style:

```
ng-sidebar[ng-reflect-opened=true] + div[_ngcontent-oer-c1] > div[_ngcontent-ocs-c0] a#show-sidebar {
    left: 300px;
}
```

But it's not working! Any suggestions?

> **Note:** Sidebar is toggling just to add style to toggle button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by **class binding**, just make a class in your CSS as:

```
.toggled {
    left: 300px;
}
```

As you have a property `_opened` in your **.ts** file which is Boolean so just add this to your desired element: `[ngClass]="{toggled : _opened}"`.
Hope it will help :)